# OCaml scan 2 values at time and put in 2 variables

Tags: ocaml

i have this code:

```
let d = scanf " %d" (fun a->a)
let nrf = read_int()
```

I want to input 2 integer values and press enter. In C language I use `scanf("%d %d", &x1, &x2);`
But in OCaml I have to press enter and then input the second value with this code.
Can someone tell how to read two integers in one line and put them in 2 variables?
Thanks for the help !

Comment: Could you edit your code to write `let` instead of `Let` ? ;-)

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
let (c, d) = Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun a b -> (a, b))
```

It looks like this when you run this code:

```
# let (c, d) = Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun a b -> (a, b));;
8 144
val c : int = 8
val d : int = 144
#
```

The second line was the input typed by the user (i.e., by me).

Comment: Thank you ! im new at ocaml this things still confuse me.

Answer (score 0):

read_int expects a string that contains an int (otherwise, it raises a Failure).
You have to use instead read_line which reads a string from the input and returns a string.
Then, you use sscanf as mentionned by Jeffrey.